# How to install the same package in several conda environments?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I have a list of several conda environment that I am using for different projects.
For example:

```sh
└[3417]± conda env list                                                                                             
# conda environments:
#
base                     /????/anaconda2
analysis_eel_data     *  /????/anaconda2/envs/analysis_eel_data
explore_cora             /????/anaconda2/envs/explore_cora
pygmt                    /????/anaconda2/envs/pygmt
python3                  /????/anaconda2/envs/python3
test_cookiecutter_pj1    /????/anaconda2/envs/test_cookiecutter_pj1
```

I was wondering if there is an 'easy' way to install the same package in several conda environments?

By easy, I mean a solution that could hold in one or two command lines?

<s>Correct me if I am wrong, I think that  `pip` could be a solution if I want the new package install in **all** my environments?</s>  [*I was wrong*]

I am also open for a solution using `pip` if it is easier than `conda`

I didn't find anything on this in the [conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#managing-environments)

Comment: `pip` and `conda` are very similar in this regard. You would still have to run the pip command for each environment. I think since you are stressing the word "easy" in the title, you might want to give us a better understanding of what easy means for you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I didnt realise that `pip` would have to be run in each environment... By 'easy', I mean a couple of command line. I edited my question!

Answer (score 1):

There's no inbuilt functionality of `conda` to do this. The simplest way is to write a `bash/shell` script that can install the package of your interest in multiple environments.

We can find the path of your `env` using the command `conda env list`. Using this, the script would look something like this

```
for env in $(conda env list); 
    do conda install -n $env <package_name>; 
done
```

Also, note that this will install it in every `env` and not equivalently the same as `several` as you mentioned. In this case, we would simply need an `if-conditional` to determine to install in that `env` or not.

Comment: Plase note - I have not tested the script since i dont have conda on my system. Do lmk if you encounter any issues with it

Comment: Thank you for suggestion a solution even if not an "easy" one

Comment: @Ihoupert No worries. I dont think it can get easier than this. Theres always technicality involved in any problems. But do add answer if you come across a solution simple than this.